# How to access user input from another method

Tags: java, user-input

I am trying to count the length of the name that the user inputs using an additional method. When I try to access the user input "ipnut from my method it has an error. What is wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LengthOfName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Type your name: ");
         String input = reader.nextLine();


   calculateCharecters(text);

}
public static int calculateCharecters(String text){

    int texts = input.length();
    System.out.println("Number of charecters: " + texts);
    return texts;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `calculateCharecters(text);` as `calculateCharecters(input);`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LengthOfName {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Type your name: ");
         String input = reader.nextLine();


   calculateCharecters(input);

}
public static int calculateCharecters(String text){

    int texts = input.length();
    System.out.println("Number of charecters: " + texts);
    return texts;
}
}
```

Comment: Ah! I knew it was something easy. All I needed was to put the user input into the parameter.

Comment: it should be. you don't have a variable named text. rt?

Answer (score 0):

```
calculateCharecters(text);
```

Should be:

```
calculateCharecters(input);
```

You need to pass your input to your method.

text is your parameter for the method you are calling.  You should pass input to text.

Answer (score 0):

change `calculateCharecters(text)` should be `calculateCharecters(input)`
and `input.length()` should be `text.length()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type your name: ");
    String input = reader.nextLine(); //"input" store the user input

    calculateCharecters(input); //and go through this metod

}

public static int calculateCharecters(String text) { // now "text" store the user input 

    int texts = text.length(); //here "texts" store the "text" lenght (text.lenght()) or number
                               //of characters

    System.out.println("Number of charecters: " + texts); //printing number of characters
    return texts; //returning number of characters so
}
```

you can do this in your main

```
int characterLength = calculateCharacters(input); //because your method return an int
System.out.println("Number of charecters: " + characterLength);
```